# Remove hidden elements from cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are some elements that are hidden in this web page. Now if I want to find the hidden elements:

```
var node =  jQuery('body')[0];
$(node).find(":hidden").remove();
```

This removes the hidden elements from the main node (which further changes the layout of the page). What I want to do is to copy(clone) the elements which are not hidden. For which I am trying this:

```
var clone = node.cloneNode(true);
$(clone).find(":hidden").remove();
```

But this removes all the elements inside the clone and not just the hidden elements (as expected, since its not in the dom). What's the best possible way to remove hidden elements from the clone.

Comment: Why are you trying to clone the body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the issue is that until your clone is re-inserted into the DOM, then all of it is being considered hidden.

Maybe you could mark the hidden elements for removal first, then clone and then remove the marked elements:

```
var $node = ... ; // jQuery object of node to be cloned
$node.find(':hidden').addClass('markedForRemoval');

var $clone = $node.clone();

$clone.find('.markedForRemoval').remove();

// tidy up:
$clone.find('.markedForRemoval').removeClass('markedForRemoval');
$node.find('.markedForRemoval').removeClass('markedForRemoval');
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/6ysq8/

Answer (score 0):

```
var clone = node.cloneNode(true);
var hiddenElements = clone.querySelectorAll('.hidden'); // if hidden elements are applied the css class hidden

for(var i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++){
    clone.removeChild(hiddenElements[i])
}
```

If there is no hidden class, iterate through all the child elements and check for the display property.

```
var children = clone.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
   if(children[i].style && children[i].style.display == 'none'){
       clone.removeChild(children[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Its not necessary that they have a hidden class.

Comment: @DeveshKumar But would it hurt to add a hidden class?   You could add the hidden class to all hidden element just prior to cloning.  If it's a problem, remove the class immediately after the clone.

Comment: @DeveshKumar: You are hiding an element intentionally. Why would anybody want to set the display: none (inline) property when you could do that easily with css.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to jQuery clone.  My method is kinda rough, but it works.

```
<div class="bla" > 
    <span class="hidden">hidden</span>
    <span class="hidden">hidden</span>
    <span class="hidden">hidden</span>
    <span > visible </span>
</div>
```

So, first, clone the parent.

```
var a = $('.bla').clone()
```

Then clone the visible children.

```
var b = $('.bla > :visible').clone() ;
```

Then add them to each other.

```
a.html(b)
```

The whole thing will be like so:

```
var a = $('.bla').clone()
var b = $('.bla > :visible').clone() ; 
a.html(b)
```

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/4Dky9/1/

Comment: This would assume that all hidden elements are direct children of the cloned node.

Comment: @JamesMontagne thats true .. i really have no idea what type of elements is he trying to select .. he can select what ever he needs like so `b = $('.bla').find(':visible').clone()` ;

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the `:visible` selector will not be enough, and you will also want a selector for styles with `height:0px`, since `display:none;` and `height:0px;` are not equivalent.

Before cloning, we need to mark the elements as visible or invisible, because once cloned, the clone is in a variable, but not on the page, so everything inside it will qualify as `:hidden`.  (Bonus: Let's make this as efficient as possible, by not hijacking the class or id fields, and instead using a custom data-attribute.)

*Identify truly hidden elements:*

```
$(node).find(':hidden').attr('data-hidden', 'true');
$(node).find('
      *[style*="height:0px"],
      *[style*="height: 0px"]
').attr('data-hidden', 'true');
```

*Deep clone the node:*

```
var clone = node.clone(true, true);
```

*Remove hidden elements:*

```
clone.find('*[data-hidden="true"]').remove();
```

Answer (score -3):

try using :

```
$(clone).children(':hidden').remove();
```

Comment: This removes all the elements like I said

Comment: This is not correct because all elements are assumed to be hidden after cloning a parent element.

Comment: As Peter T. and Devesh Kumar said, the clone is not rendered on the page, because it's just a clone, so everything in it is technically "hidden" and this wipes out the clone.